# Initializing a static final int from static block or method and using it in annotations

Tags: java, spring, junit, testng

I have the following Foo test class and Bar test class files

```
public class Foo{

  public static final int timeLimit;

  static{
    timeLimit=10000;
  }

  @Test(timeOut=timeLimit)
  public void fooTest{
    //timeout annotation is just used to specify the 
    //maximum execution time for this test method
  }
}


public class Bar{

  public static final int timeLimit=10000;

  @Test(timeOut=timeLimit)
  public void barTest{
    //timeout annotation is just used to specify the 
    //maximum execution time for this test method
  }
}
```

when I try to compile these two classes Bar compiles properly, but Foo class says that timeout should be assigned a constant value, can some one explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's because primitive `public static final` fields are actually inlined by the compiler when referenced from another class. If you have to load the other class for it to receive a value, the compiler can't do this.

I only found this implicitly in the JLS unfortunately:

> Note that static fields that are constant variables (§4.12.4) are
>   initialized before other static fields (§12.4.2). This also applies in
>   interfaces (§9.3.1). Such fields will never be observed to have their
>   default initial values (§4.12.5), even by devious programs.

Clearly if they have to be initialized before other static fields, they can't be initialized in static blocks.

Comment: I don't see how your first paragraph applies. There's no reference to another class' field.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It comes from the demand for conditional compilation. If you compile a class later that refers to `Foo.timeLimit`, it should be able to determine the value of the constant variable from the already compiled `Foo.class`

Comment: @Manipal Please accept Sotirios's answer instead of mine as that is the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

Annotation attributes can only be assigned [constant expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) (and a [few other types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.1)).

In `Foo`

```
public static final int timeLimit;

static{
    timeLimit=10000;
}

@Test(timeOut=timeLimit)
```

the variable `timeLimit` is not a constant expression.

Comment: You're right, this should be the accepted answer, as it gives a full explanation why it should be a constant expression.